# Cambiar los botones del confirm() de JavaScipt

Tags: javascript

Como puedo cambiar el texto de los botones que aparecen en la función `confirm()` de JavaScript? 
Los textos por default son "Aceptar" y "Cancelar". Yo quisiera poner "Si" y "No". Alguna idea?

Comment: No se puede propiamente los de confirm(). Te recomendaría hacer un modal o un popup personalizado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacer un popup personalizado o utiliza la librería sweetalert, que te permite personalizar los mensajes a presentar.

```js
function confirmFunction() {
  swal({
    title: "Confirmar Accion",
    text: "Se realizara la accion correspondiente",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    cancelButtonColor: '#f7505a',
    confirmButtonText: "SI",
    cancelButtonText: "NO"

  }).then(function() {
    $('#txt_test').val(idtema);
    $('#formTest').submit();
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.3.5/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<form name="formTest" id="formTest" method="post">
  <input type="button" name="txt_test" id="txt_test" onclick="confirmFunction();" value="Confirmar" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo con el estándar que define `confirm()`, no hay forma de especificar etiquetas de botones personalizados.

https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html#simple-dialogs

El navegador debe mostrar un mensaje de OK / Cancelar para cumplir con el estándar HTML5.

Una alternativa es utilizar un `modal`

algo como esto;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_boton').on('click', function () {
    myApp.confirm('Estas seguro?', 'Title', function () {
      $('.boton_no').text("No");
      $('.boton_si').text("SI");
  });
});
```

> NOTA: Si utilizaras este ejemplo debes agregar Jquery en tu proyecto.

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta se podría beneficiar bastante si tuviese un ejemplo completo ejecutable. Podés hacerlo desde el botón `<>` del editor.